# I have separated the dataset into numeric and categorical but the names of the numeric columns have changed to numbers

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have separated the dataset into numeric and categorical but the names of the numeric columns have changed to numbers.

`numeric_data = df.select_dtypes(include=[np.number]) categorical_data = df.select_dtypes(exclude=[np.number])`

numeric index before separete = Alley, Street , LotFrontage...
after sparet = 0, 1, 2...

Comment: Can you include the code that is providing the output?